# How to control mapply output

Tags: r, output, mapply

I have been using R for about a month now, and I need help to control the output of mapply. I have provided a test case of reproducible code here. I would like the output to give a list of vectors with integer values, but instead I get a list that combines the values of x1 with a list of numbers.

So how do I get output that does not have x1, "=" but has for each of the input values a separate integer vector?  More generally, how is the output from mapply controlled?

(Any suggestions for improving my mapply function would also be appreciated, as maybe the problem lies there)

```
x1 <- c(".", ".|.", ".", ".|.", ".")
x2 <- c(135L, 9L, 21L, 35L, 47L)
# mapply in x, replace “.” with index number of string, and add to y-1 to make a vector of integers for each line)
x3 <- mapply(function(x,y){(y-1)+unlist(gregexpr("[.]", x))},x=x1,y=x2)
dput(x3)
list(. = 135, `.|.` = c(9, 11), . = 21, `.|.` = c(35, 37), . = 47)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your expected output? Maybe provide two examples of inputs and expected output.

Comment: x3 doesn't have equal signs in it. dput() is a function that creates a string that can recreate your object x3. x3 is a nice list(albeit with wierd names)

Comment: Could you provide an example regarding the way that the output should appear please?

Comment: Maybe you just want to `unname()` the list?

Comment: This is what I would like the output to look like.
    [[1]]
    [1] 135L
    
    [[2]]
    [[2]][1] 9L
    
    [[2]]
    [[2]][2] 11L
    
    [[3]]
    [1] 21L
    
    [[4]]
    [[4]][1] 35L
    
    [[4]]
    [[4]][2] 37L
    
    [[5]]
    [1] 47L

Comment: Mr Flick, Thank you! The unname command got rid of the x1 and "=" from the output, but I cannot coerce the output into integers using as.integer. Also, is it a general property of mapply to name the output?